# Django forms - defined value

Tags: python, django, django-forms

How to set defined value for form ?

**Model**:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    foo=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**Form**:

```
class AddForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model=Record
```

**View**:

```
class AddRecord(CreateView):
    template_name="any/any.html"
    form_class=AddForm
    model=Record
```

If send `<input type="text" name="user" value="ANY_USER_ID"/>`  and change record for any user

How to set  field user default value is: request.session.user

Answer (score 2):

You can override [`get_initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial) on your form class to return a dictionary of initial data:

```
class AddRecord(CreateView):
    def get_initial(self):
        return {'user': self.request.user}
```

But what you actually really want to do is not to show the user on the form at all, but set it automatically on save, as [the documentation describes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user).